# how to create function that return Observable after verifications?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want to return an http.get observable after checking if the token is valid and then getting the right url, at the end return a get observable. I wrote this code, but doesn't compile, `error : A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

```
getListObs<T>(target):Observable<T>{
this.tokenifyObs().subscribe(
  token => {
    console.log("get list of objects ")
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      let myUrl = this.urls_list[this.baseUrl] + this.urls_list[target];
      observer.next(myUrl);
    })
    .subscribe( (myUrl)=>{
      return this.http.get<T[]>(myUrl)
    })
  })
```

}

code of tokenifyOsb method:

```
    tokenifyObs():Observable<String>{
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      console.log("checking token.. ")
      if(! this.token){
        let token = sessionStorage.getItem("token")
        this.token = token
        this.header.headers["authorization"] = this.auth + token;
        this.validAuth = true
      }
      console.log("token is : ", this.token)
      observer.next(this.token);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you are getting means that you specified the return type for your method `getListObs<T>(target):Observable<T>` but you are not returning anything. Simply writing `return this.tokenifyObs().subscribe(...` will remove the typescript error. This however will return a subscription, not an Observable. You don't need to subscribe in this method, just return the observable. I haven't seen your entire code but I assume this is where you could start:

```
getListObs<T>(target):Observable<T>{
  return this.tokenifyObs()
    .switchMap(token => { // you are not using token anywhere so you can replace it with ()
        let myUrl = this.urls_list[this.baseUrl] + this.urls_list[target];
        return this.http.get<T>(myUrl);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I transformed the code as you said, and now an other error : 'Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<string>'.' even if I left it as template the error is talking about string? I don't understand what that means

Comment: here are my includes import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError, map, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: can you post the code for the `this.tokenifyObs()` method?

Comment: Also, try importing like this: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';` It has more operators than  `'rxjs/Observable'` and should remove the error.

Comment: Yes importing Observable from Rx changed the error, now the error moved from switchMap to the return and says :
Type 'Observable<T[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'. Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer. You should return just one observable, not an array. Or if you are returning an array, specify it in the return type of the method.

Comment: I just saw that in the same time, thanks Boris, you saved me a lot of headach and time

Comment: Great! Happy to help!